# I'm not able to import items.py file in my main spider file[scrapy]

Tags: python, scrapy

[project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TvnwZ.png)

I'm trying to import my items file into shop.py file. I also tried [from ..items import ShopcluesItem] but it doesn't work. Please tell me what is it I'm doing wrong here?

```
import scrapy
from items import ShopcluesItem

class ShopSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'shop'
    allowed_domains = ['shopclues.com']
    start_urls = ['https://www.shopclues.com/mobiles-smartphones.html?sort_by=bestsellers']

    def parse(self, response):

        items = QuotetutorialItem()

        titles = response.css('img::attr(title)').extract()
        images = response.css('img::attr(data-img)').extract()
        prices = response.css('.p_price::text').extract()
        discounts = response.css('.prd_discount::text').extract()

        for item in zip(titles, prices, images, discounts):
            scraped_info = {
                'title': item[0],
                'price': item[1],
                'image_urls': [item[2]],  # Set's the url for scrapy to download images
                'discount': item[3]
            }

            yield scraped_info

            has_next = response.css('.load-more').extract()
            if has_next:
                next_page = response.meta.get('next_page', 1) + 1
                url = response.urljoin(response.css('script').re_first("'(\?searchId.*page=)'") + str(next_page))
                yield Request(url, meta={'next_page': next_page})
```

Comment: Try `from YOUR_PROJECT_NAME.items import ShopcluesItem`

Comment: it's still not working.

Comment: how is you project file structure?

Comment: I've taken a screenshot and edited it please check

Comment: Could you post the complete error message?

Comment: okay, it worked. Thanks